# For each column value [substring], find match in other column [string]

Tags: python, pandas

I'm quite new to python to this might be a basic question. If so, sorry in advance!

I'm trying to accomplish the following:

1. For each row, search for the value of `df3['court_short']` in column `court_region_df[['court_long']]`.
2. If there is a match in the column `court_region_df[['court_long']]` then select that row's value for `court_region_df[['hmcts_region']]` and copy it to `df3['region']`

The value that `df3['court_short']` takes is a string, typically a town name something like that, whereas `court_region_df[['court_long']]` takes the value of a longer string for example a full address.

I'm a bit lost about first how to accomplish step 1. Most of the python search functions I've found seem don't seem suited to finding a particular pattern in a longer string.

Comment: In Python, finding a short string in a longer string is very easy: `'ab' in 'abc'` --> `True`. Beyond that, you probably want to do a (temporary) join operation. Maybe share a sample of your data?

Comment: Yep I can. Here is one of the datasets: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1J4ztI8_8CI3pmCqnJQzs8xEQ4xyIumRS and here is the other: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Lpbmq3tYC85hIS9k4s2e-MNjBkMDdHVn  . I'm trying to take for example 'Plymouth' from Plymouth Crown Court, and find look in the other dataset for Plymouth, and take the 'region' back to the first dataset. Edit: I've just seen your other reply, I'll try that now thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a toy example, but it's roughly the same as yours:

```
d = pd.DataFrame([['aa', 'bb'], ['cc', 'dd']], columns=['a', 'b'])
e = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'E'], ['c', '.']], columns=['a', 'b'])

e['c'] = e['a'].apply(lambda x: (d[d['a'].str.contains(x)]['b']))[0]
```

Output:

```
    a   b   c
0   a   E   bb
1   c   .   NaN
```

EDIT: I tried with your data, and was able to come up with a non-vectorised solution, which is a little slow but manageable (takes a couple of seconds with the file you shared). Here it is:

```
court_region_df = pd.read_csv('courts (1).csv')
df3 = pd.read_csv('cjs-national-court-codes-9 (2).csv', names=['court_short'], header=0)
court_region_df = court_region_df.rename(columns={'court':'court_long'})

for idx in df3.index:
    x = df3.loc[idx,'court_short']
    region = court_region_df[court_region_df.iloc[:,0].str.contains(x, case=False, regex=False)]['hmcts_region']
    df3.loc[idx, 'region'] = [region.values[0] if len(region) > 0 else np.nan][0]
```

Slightly faster is to stash them in a dictionary and avoid using Pandas magic at all:

```
court_to_region = pd.Series(court_region_df.hmcts_region.values, index=court_region_df.court_long.str.lower()).to_dict()

regions = []
for i in df3.court_short.values:
    region = np.nan
    for key in court_to_region.keys():
        if i.lower() in key:
            region = court_to_region[key]
    regions.append(region)
df3['region'] = regions
```

Result:

```
df3[~df3.isna().any(axis=1)]

    court_short                 region
280     Birmingham Crown Court  midlands
301     Ipswich Crown Court     south_east
```

As you can see, given the data you shared, this returns just two matches. You might want to look into a fuzzier matching system.

Comment: With this code -> court_id['region'] = court_id['court_short'].apply(lambda x: (court_region_df[court_region_df['court'].str.contains(x)]['hmcts_region']))[0] ->I'm getting an error 'KeyError: 0; duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality'. However there shouldn't be duplicate columns in either dataset. Could I be getting this error because the dataframes are different sizes?

Comment: The size difference shouldn't matter. I added a lot to my answer, using your data - check it out.

Comment: Thanks thats great!

Comment: This code only produces a single NaN in the column?